# DB connection pool not being used in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

**Context:**

I am using database/sql to maintain a pool of open connections. The configuration I'm using is as follows: maxIdleConnections = 20, maxOpenConnections = 100. I'm also printing the [DBStats](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Stats).

**Issue:**

Now some of the logs look like this:

```
DB stats: {MaxOpenConnections:100 OpenConnections:23 InUse:3 Idle:20 WaitCount:0 WaitDuration:0s MaxIdleClosed:25440 MaxIdleTimeClosed:0 MaxLifetimeClosed:1}
```

**Question:**

Why are idle connections not being used and new connections being created? in the above example, we can see that there are 20 idle connections but still 3 new connections were created (InUse:3).

Comment: You are only looking at the stats at a given point in time. You don't know how you got here. Maybe when those new connections were created there weren't any idle.